# Kubernetes - Metrics not showing after reboot

Tags: kubernetes, metrics

I have an on prem K8s cluster, using 2 pieces of hardware - a master on each.

`kubectl get nodes
NAME      STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
master1   Ready    master   52d   v1.15.3
master2   Ready    master   52d   v1.15.3
node2     Ready    <none>   52d   v1.15.3
node3     Ready    <none>   52d   v1.15.3
node4     Ready    <none>   52d   v1.15.3`

After a reboot of a master node to upgrade memory - the metrics are no longer showing, they did before the reboot.

`kubectl top nodes
NAME      CPU(cores)   CPU%   MEMORY(bytes)   MEMORY%
master2   251m         13%    1548Mi          66%
node2     234m         12%    1875Mi          41%
node3     137m         7%     1721Mi          38%
node4     588m         30%    2661Mi          48%
master1   <unknown>                           <unknown>               <unknown>               <unknown>`

`kubectl get pods -n kube-system
NAME                                       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
calico-kube-controllers-7b9f9648d8-8525s   1/1     Running   0          48d
calico-node-66n4f                          1/1     Running   2          48d
calico-node-cml5f                          1/1     Running   2          48d
calico-node-hdf7c                          1/1     Running   0          48d
calico-node-pr2zc                          1/1     Running   3          48d
calico-node-wbldc                          1/1     Running   6          48d
coredns-74c9d4d795-8jkcg                   1/1     Running   0          48d
coredns-74c9d4d795-psnqd                   1/1     Running   0          19h
dns-autoscaler-7d95989447-mlpxt            1/1     Running   0          19h
heapster-55c5f89fbd-xb2n7                  2/2     Running   2          4d3h
kube-apiserver-master1                     1/1     Running   2          48d
kube-apiserver-master2                     1/1     Running   0          48d
kube-controller-manager-master1            1/1     Running   2          48d
kube-controller-manager-master2            1/1     Running   0          48d
kube-proxy-hngdr                           1/1     Running   6          48d
kube-proxy-mk9pn                           1/1     Running   0          48d
kube-proxy-t4954                           1/1     Running   2          48d
kube-proxy-wjh56                           1/1     Running   3          48d
kube-proxy-ww56g                           1/1     Running   2          48d
kube-scheduler-master1                     1/1     Running   2          48d
kube-scheduler-master2                     1/1     Running   0          48d
kubernetes-dashboard-7d75c474bb-bg5s4      1/1     Running   0          4d3h
metrics-server-5889f5b847-dl6zl            1/1     Running   2          13d
nginx-proxy-node2                          1/1     Running   9          52d
nginx-proxy-node3                          1/1     Running   6          52d
nginx-proxy-node4                          1/1     Running   7          52d
nodelocaldns-87vdg                         1/1     Running   0          48d
nodelocaldns-f2d2c                         1/1     Running   6          48d
nodelocaldns-p8vmj                         1/1     Running   2          48d
nodelocaldns-sn8gk                         1/1     Running   3          48d
nodelocaldns-vd62b                         1/1     Running   2          48d
tiller-deploy-767d9b9584-7ljjb             1/1     Running   4          4d3h`

All services running ok.

Any ideas?

```
`kubectl describe node master1
`Name:               master1
`Roles:              master
`Labels:             beta.kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
`                    beta.kubernetes.io/os=linux
`                    kubernetes.io/arch=amd64
`                    kubernetes.io/hostname=master1
`                    kubernetes.io/os=linux
`                    node-role.kubernetes.io/master=
`Annotations:        kubeadm.alpha.kubernetes.io/cri-socket: `/var/run/dockershim.sock
`                    node.alpha.kubernetes.io/ttl: 0
`                    volumes.kubernetes.io/controller-managed-attach-detach: `true
`CreationTimestamp:  Fri, 16 Aug 2019 14:26:15 +0000
`Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
`Unschedulable:      false
`Conditions:
`  Type                 Status  LastHeartbeatTime                 `LastTransitionTime                Reason                       Message
`  ----                 ------  -----------------                 ------------`------                ------                       -------
`  NetworkUnavailable   False   Tue, 08 Oct 2019 08:24:42 +0000   Tue, 08 Oct `2019 08:24:42 +0000   CalicoIsUp                   Calico is running on this `node
`  MemoryPressure       False   Wed, 09 Oct 2019 14:54:13 +0000   Tue, 08 Oct `2019 08:24:35 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientMemory   kubelet has sufficient `memory available
`  DiskPressure         False   Wed, 09 Oct 2019 14:54:13 +0000   Tue, 08 Oct `2019 08:24:35 +0000   KubeletHasNoDiskPressure     kubelet has no disk `pressure
`  PIDPressure          False   Wed, 09 Oct 2019 14:54:13 +0000   Tue, 08 Oct `2019 08:24:35 +0000   KubeletHasSufficientPID      kubelet has sufficient PID `available
`  Ready                True    Wed, 09 Oct 2019 14:54:13 +0000   Tue, 08 Oct `2019 08:24:35 +0000   KubeletReady                 kubelet is posting ready `status. AppArmor enabled
`Addresses:
`  InternalIP:  10.200.40.23
`  Hostname:    master1
`Capacity:
` cpu:                2
` ephemeral-storage:  41019616Ki
` hugepages-2Mi:      0
` memory:             4948784Ki
` pods:               110
`Allocatable:
` cpu:                1800m
` ephemeral-storage:  37803678044
` hugepages-2Mi:      0
` memory:             4346384Ki
` pods:               110
`System Info:
` Machine ID:                 0994b13409574735a1682c5fd60c9c2c
` System UUID:                0994B134-0957-4735-A168-2C5FD60C9C2C
` Boot ID:                    3d886b98-ba60-4fa2-b1b1-3a603fcb97bb
` Kernel Version:             4.15.0-65-generic
` OS Image:                   Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS
` Operating System:           linux
` Architecture:               amd64
` Container Runtime Version:  docker://18.9.7
` Kubelet Version:            v1.15.3
` Kube-Proxy Version:         v1.15.3
`PodCIDR:                     10.233.64.0/24
`Non-terminated Pods:         (6 in total)
`  Namespace                  Name                               CPU Requests  `CPU Limits  Memory Requests  Memory Limits  AGE
`  ---------                  ----                               ------------  `----------  ---------------  -------------  ---
`  kube-system                calico-node-cml5f                  150m (8%)     `300m (16%)  64M (1%)         500M (11%)     49d
`  kube-system                kube-apiserver-master1             250m (13%)    `0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         49d
`  kube-system                kube-controller-manager-master1    200m (11%)    `0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         49d
`  kube-system                kube-proxy-t4954                   0 (0%)        `0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         49d
`  kube-system                kube-scheduler-master1             100m (5%)     `0 (0%)      0 (0%)           0 (0%)         49d
`  kube-system                nodelocaldns-p8vmj                 100m (5%)     `0 (0%)      70Mi (1%)        170Mi (4%)     49d
`Allocated resources:
`  (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
`  Resource           Requests        Limits
`  --------           --------        ------
`  cpu                800m (44%)      300m (16%)
`  memory             137400320 (3%)  678257920 (15%)
`  ephemeral-storage  0 (0%)          0 (0%)``
```

Comment: How did you performed the restart? Why `kubectl get nodes` shows both masters with the same age?

Comment: The nodes are VM's. attempted to drain the master1 node - which failed. I then applied the cordon to master1 - shut down the VM - added memory. Restarted the VM, had to restart Docker && Kubelet svc

Comment: How have you installed your cluster? How are your masters configured, where is etcd?

Comment: Deployed using ansible/kubespray - etcd is healthy - 3 nodes

Comment: provide output of `kubectl describe nodes master1`

Comment: Nether master nodes have any disk, cpu or memory issues

Comment: Too many chars for all of it!

Comment: Edit the question(on top) and put it there, or link for it.

Comment: Formatting not the best!

Comment: Looking at logs of metrics-server -       1 manager.go:111] unable to fully collect metrics: unable to fully scrape metrics from source kubelet_summary:master1: unable to fetch metrics from Kubelet master1 (10.200.40.23): Get https://10.200.40.23:10250/stats/summary?only_cpu_and_memory=true: context deadline exceeded

Comment: Post the steps you used to setup the cluster. I will try to set it up same way and debug.